# Proving a deformation retract

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the unit disk with antipodal points on the boundary identified. As a subset, consider this disk, where an open disk around the center is deleted.

I want to prove that this subset deformation retracts onto the boundary, which should be homeomorphic to do, but have no idea where to begin. I would naturally think to apply the 'radial' map as a retract, but I am stuck because of the identification of the antipodal points...

I am working with the 'weak' definition of deformation retract.

Comment: Just make sure that the retraction and the deformation respect the equivalence relation, which is obvious in this case.

Comment: Sure, but how do you write this down? If I take the retaction $x \mapsto r(x) = \frac{x}{||x||}$, then how can I see that this still preserves the equivalence? I am having a hard time writing this down

Comment: Assume $y=-x$. Prove that $r(y)=-r(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the annulus by $X$ and let $q$ be the quotient projection. Radial map $F(x,t) = (1-t) x + t \frac{x}{||x||}$ gives you a deformation retraction of the annulus to the its boundary. If you postcompose this with $q$, you obtain the desired deformation retraction.